# Is there a way to whitelist the master in HTML5 application cache?

Tags: html, caching, cache-manifest

Here is my manifest :

```
CACHE MANIFEST
CACHE:
//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js
NETWORK:
*
```

My `index.html` which defines that manifest (`<html manifest="app.manifest>`) is always stored as "`Master`" even with the `NETWORK` wildcard part of my manifest.

The problem is that my MASTER `index.html` is stored in the cache... and won't be refreshed if it changes on the server side if the manifest file is not updated.

I've seen multiple not really beautiful solutions to that problem (like the [iframe solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9287604/535203)), so my question is : is there a clean HTML 5 way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

The clean way to do it is to only have static content in your `index.html` file then load the data dynamically (eg. via AJAX) to create the page the user sees.  An alternative would be to have a big link which says 'Enable Offline Support' which links to a page with the manifest link in it.

Other than that, the `iframe` solution *is* the cleanest way - you're hacking around the intended use of AppCache, why do you expect that to be 'clean'?  What application scenario do you have that `jquery-2.0.3.min.js` needs to be available offline but not the index page of the app which accesses it?