# How to use Appcache with web frameworks?

Tags: node.js, html, tornado, html5-appcache, offline-caching

I have a problem about changing the `main page`, I use [`Tornado`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/), and in Tornado, there is a special value which is generated everytime the server is reached, it is a token to avoid `xsrf attack`, but when I use `.appcache` file, the problem is that it caches everything! and I only show to cache `static` like `css, js, fonts`, here is what it contains:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# v = 2
/static/css/meteo.css
/static/css/semantic.min.css
/static/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js
/static/css/main.css
/static/js/semantic.min.js
/static/js/geo.js
/static/js/meteo.js
/static/fonts/icons.woff2
/static/fonts/icons.woff
/static/fonts/WeatherIcons-Regular.woff
NETWORK:
/
FALLBACK:
```

It doesent work, the `/` get cached!

So how to do this with new Framework, where it we dont make the `html` file in the route, but the `uri` that is bound to a function/class?

[Here is a video I made about it](http://youtu.be/ycpg_Q1ubRc)

And it seems that the `master` is always cached :

[image]

Update: [From this page](http://www.webdirections.org/blog/appcache-not-so-much-a-douchebag-as-a-complete-pain-in-the/), it is noway!

> But, you say, why don’t we not cache the HTML file, but cache all the rest.
>   Well. AppCache has a concept of “master entries”. A master entry is an HTML file that includes a manifest attribute in the html element that points to a manifest file (which is the only way to create an HTML5 appcache BTW). Any such HTML file is automatically added to the cache. This makes sense a lot of the time, but not always. In particular, when an HTML document changes frequently, we won’t want it cached (as a stale version of the page will most likely be served to the user as we just saw).
>
> **Is there no way to over-​​ride this? Well, AppCache has the idea of a
>   NETWORK whitelist, which instructs the appcache to always use the
>   online version of a file. What if we add HTML files we don’t want
>   cached to this? Sorry, no dice. HTML files in a master entry stay
>   cached, even when included in the NETWORK whitelist. See what I mean.
>   Poor AppCache didn’t make these rules. He’s just following them
>   literally. He’s not a douchebag, he’s a pain in the %^&*, a total
>   “jobs-​​worth”.**

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9287604/861487):

I made a `hack.html` which contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Hack 4 Manifest</title>
</head>

<body>
  {% raw xsrf_form_html() %}
</body>
</html>
```

And then

Add this in the main page:

```
<iframe style='display: none;' src='/hack'></iframe>
```

And then in Tornado:

```
(r"/hack", handlers.Hack),

class Hack(MainHandler):
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        self.render("hack.html")
```

And then I use the javascript call:

```
xsrf = $("iframe").contents().find("input").val()
$("#laat").html('<input id="lat" type="hidden" name="lat"></input><input type="hidden" name="_xsrf" value='+xsrf+'><input id="lon" type="hidden" name="lon"></input><input class="ui fluid massive yellow button" value="Get forecast" type="submit"/>');
```